# Efficiently validate nested JSON schema/config on front end

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, data-structures, ajv

I have following JSON config in a `typescript` project. I would like to validate this on the front-end during run-time. I am looking for a solution similar to `node-convict`.

I need to validate

1. unique `id` / No duplicate Id.
2. unique name.
3. required property non empty `type`
4. Multiple children types conditionally e.g. if type === `folder` they
   should have `children` prop. it can be an empty array.
5. Nested Objects at multiple levels.

I've found `AJV`. AJV docs only refer to whole object being unique not specific properties. I could potentially come up with my own and do some recursive validation. However, I am looking for most efficient solution whether using ajv, another library or an efficient data structure that I could use to validate this.

If using external library it need to be compatible with typescript. I am NOT looking for typescript compile-time validation.

```
[{
    "type": "folder",
    "name": "",
    "id": 1, // UUID
    "chldren": [{
            "id": 11, // UUID
            "type": "table", // TABLE TYPE
            "name": "Some Table 1",
            "meta": {},
            "dataSource": "..........."
        },
        {
            "type": "folder", // FOLDER TYPE
            "name": "",
            "id": 111, // UUID
            "chldren": [{
                "type": "folder",
                "name": "",
                "id": 1111, // UUID
                "chldren": [{
                    "id": 11111, // UUID
                    "type": "table",
                    "name": "Some Another Table",
                    "meta": {},
                    "dataSource": "..........."
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [Joi](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/) data validation library. It has had [browser support](https://twitter.com/eranhammer/status/1159245737261064193?s=20) since version 16.

An example is as follows e.g.

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';

const schema = Joi.object({
    type: Joi.string()
        .alphanum()
        .required(),

    id: Joi.number()
        .integer()

    // I've not defined the whole schema for your object...
})
```

You can then validate your object using:

```
schema.validate({ type: 'folder', id: 1 });
// -> { error: null, value: { type: 'folder', id: 1 }}
```

Or:

```
try {
    const value = await schema.validateAsync({ type: 'folder', id: 1 });
}
catch (err) { }
```

You can get the TypeScript typings for Joi from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/joi).

An example of this working can be found [here](https://repl.it/@8enSmith/joi-in-a-browser).

Comment: `Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first` It's throwing this error when I try to compile. I've used `Joi` before but with NodeJS.

Comment: Joi 16+ should be useable from the browser. If you are having difficult also check out joi-browser on github.

Comment: @MonteCristo For completeness I've added a working example.

Comment: I have a follow up question wonder if you could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695894/joi-deep-nested-recursive-array-of-alternative-objects-validation